How far away can I put the tank from the pressure switch?
I am looking to see how far away I can put the tank from the pressure switch. I have a crawl space with minimal height and access near the switch due to steel girders (mfg home). I can put one in the middle of the crawlspace but that would make it about 12 ft away from the switch.


What's preventing you from putting the switch at the tank, no matter where the tank goes?

Just major plumbing reconfiguration in a 30" crawlspace.

And wiring configuration. I'm now looking at 2 20gal horizontal connection.  Believe I just need to have the switch closer to one and not the other.

You see a problem, we can't imagine what it is from your description. A sketch would clarify the issue and attract answers. Click edit under your question, use the mountains and moon icon to add an image.

Saw one online.  See if I can download it and add to this.

"Saw one online." Please put a link to where you found it. Stack Exchange rules require attribution for pictures posted from outside sources.

If you stop the pump, empty both tanks of water, set the correct air pressure in the tank near the switch, then set the air pressure in the remote tank 2-4 psi higher before you turn the pump on to refill the system, this will guarantee that the remote tank stops filling before the tank near the switch.
That will prevent the short cycling that having a tank far from the switch can cause. By having the pressure a little too high in one tank, you will lose a small amount of capacity that the added tank brings, but the amount will be negligible and the pump protection valuable.
EDIT: Based on further comments, if this below is what you want to do, I recommend you don't do it.

Setting up like this will cause short cycles and could cause the pump to chatter on and off repeatedly under certain conditions of flow. You could wear out your pump pretty quickly that way.
Note that if you can run a pipe 12 feet, you can run wire the same distance and put the switch wherever the tank is.

Are you referring to my diagram & having 2 tanks or to my original question of 1 tank only that is about 12' from the pressure switch?

@Tim I'm referring to your diagram, assuming it is an accurate depiction of what you want to do, namely, add a second tank distant from an existing tank and switch. If that's not what you want to do, either modify the diagram you provided or make a new one, or take the diagram down and explain in words what you want to do in a way that others who can't see your crawlspace can understand.

Ok. Thx for clarification. Yes I could run wire it's just that I'm working in a 34" crawlspace between girders.

Have you ever had knowledge of installing 2 smaller tanks instead of 1 larger tank?

@Tim Yes, nothing wrong with that if they are next to each other on the short legs of a T with the pressure switch on the long leg of the T, and both tanks have air at the same pressure. Multiple tanks at a distance, not so much but I do remember one on this site with multiple dwellings on a single property sharing a single pump and switch. That one had check valves to keep distant tanks from backfeeding the plumbing near the switch.

Yes, I think that is my plan.  2 tanks pretty much directly next to each other.  The first tank would be about 18"-24" from the pressure switch much as my one tank is currently.  Both tanks are pre charged to 38.

I'm editing my original question with a pic I just took to show you my set up currently.  Take a look a tell me your thoughts with adding the 2 smaller tanks from you and advice above. Appreciate all your help. Btw! Red circle is the well supply line, yellow is the supply directly to my tank. Was just going to cut the poly line to current tank and shorten the distance & connect to 2 tanks that will be together.
